# Abort clock script execution on the page

Tags: javascript

I have a particular problem. There is a page with a clock, i need to stop them. I've tried something like `throw new Error()` or infinite/recursive loops, didn't help. This is not my site or script so i can't change anything, is there any way to stop them from firebug/chrome console?

Comment: What's the page... In Chrome's developer tools you can go in and edit the JS of a page. The clock is probably running in an infinite loop, one iteration is one tick. Just give it a condition that evaluates to `false` and it won't tick anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually Disable JavaScript did what i need, without removing/reloading the page.

Answer (score 2):

This will stop any clocks whose compenents are contained in the DOM:

```
document.removeChild(document.documentElement);
```

This will probably work in most cases, but it is possible that the clock script will clear and redraw the clock on the document element with every iteration. If so, this is the most effective option I can think of:

```
window.close();
```

These might be overkill for your purposes, but unless you include more details about the clock or give a demo link, I can't really tell you anything more specific.

Comment: removeChild() good method, but this is an app on JS, so it removes everything =( and the second method, close current tab. But still thanks